# Virtual Box Shared folders on Mac backup to external harddrive

Tags: macos, windows-8, virtualbox

So I found out how to share folders using Virtual Box and running Windows 8.

I was wondering, if I save files or projects from Windows 8 to the shared folder on my Mac, will TimeMachine backup those files onto my external harddrive?  The hard drive is of course formatted for Mac because of that whole debockel,  but that is besides the point. Even though the files were made in Windows.

Also...My assumption is that I would not be able to access the files on my external formatted hard drive from Virtual Box running Windows 8.  Is this true?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, you cannot access the files on a journaled formatted hard drive from Windows without extra software. If I understand you correctly, you are trying to backup files created in the Windows VM within your Time Machine backup hard drive?

I'm sure you have solved this by now, but you should consider backing up the VM itself. If the files on the Windows Machine are important you can leave them in a shared folder and have time machine back up that folder.